# How to take a screenshot of Chromium's search suggestions and instant search results

Tags: chromium, screenshot

I've been trying to take screenshots of Chromium's Google search suggestions as I type. I would also like to include Google's instant search results.

I tried using the Print Screen key, and also Ubuntu's 12.04 gnome-screenshot utility.

The issue is that when I press PrtScr, focus is off Chromium's window, which causes it to automatically abort the search, and show the webpage that was on the screen when I started typing a new search.

You can see in the screenshot below, that I typed *www.askub*, and Google's search suggestion was *www.askubuntu*, among other suggestions. An instant search result appeared that included this site as the first hit. But none of these things are in the screenshot.

[image: This is a screenshot of an attempt to search for AskUbuntu]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you start the Screenshot application manually (search for Screenshot in the Dash), it should show a window that looks like this:

[image]

If you select `Grab the current window` and set an appropriate delay, you should be able to capture pop up menus, the web browser quick search results, etc.  Just hit the `Take Screenshot` button, perform your quick search and wait until the delay timer completes.

Answer (score 4):

For that you'll need an advance screenshot program. Like "[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)"

Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.

You can install "Shutter" using terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

**How to use?**

Press Super key (Windows key) or click on the dash button to open the Unity dash, Search for "Shutter" and open it.

1. In the lower right corner set the delay to 10 seconds.
2. Click on "Window" button to capture a window.

[image]

As you'll click on "Window" button the shutter will disappear, Now move your cursor to Chromium and click on it.

[image]

After 10 seconds "Shutter" will take the screenshot of Chromium. Now start typing in url bar and wait.

Hare's a result!

[image]

Comment: This might be a solution, but @james-henstridge's solution is simpler and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the native screenshot tool which is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and you will see small cross hairs. Just use it to mark the area then you save the screenshot and your done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. Pressing anything makes the instant search abort.