# Screenshot problem Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, screenshot

When I want to take a screenshot with gnome-screenshot of my browser (chromium), pdf-viewer (Document Viewer), nautilus or even texmaker it takes a screenshot of the desktop or the window behind the current active window and sometimes it works as desired. This happens with the options "*Grab the whole screen*", "*Select area to grab*" and "*Grab the current window*". For all three options the behavior is not the same every time! Here is a summary of the 3 behaviors:

- screenshot of desktop through actual active window and the windows behind
- screenshot of the window behind the actual active window
- screenshot of actual active window (desired event!)

---

**EDIT1:**
new behavior found taking a screenshot ("select area to grab") of my clock in the task-bar.

picture taken at 10:35:30:
[image]

picture taken at 10:35:40 (**10 seconds later**):
[image]

picture taken at 10:40:34 (**10 minutes later**):
[image]

It appears to take on two different times a picture of a old "frozen" screen with the same time displaying on the clock (time: 10:14:43).

HELP!

---

**EDIT2:**
took a screencast with simplescreenrecorder to document the my problem/bug

[here the link to the video](https://youtu.be/EV2oorPKyN0)

Looking at the video i noticed a flickering between two screens but while taking the screencast never saw a flickering. It flickers between the actual screen (right time in the menu bar) and a old screen from the "past" (wrong time in the menu bar).

I have:

- nvidia GM107GLM Quadro M1000M
- intel graphic HD P530 chip

I'm using **nvidia-367 367.35** driver.

Comment: ASkUbuntu is not a bug tracker‼ Please use Launchpad. http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/40581

Comment: @LiveWireBT I don't think this is a bug so much as a lack of understanding.   Have you been able to duplicate the OPs problem?

Comment: Thank you! @ElderGeek Yes, i can reproduce the already mentioned bugs using the UI of gnome screenshot and also using the shortcuts.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  It works flawlessly for me under 16.04. Have you tried a RAM test? I imagine a stuck bit could cause this issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502

Comment: I have a UEFI system so memtest86+ is deactivated. Should i do the RAM test with on memtest86 ISO on a bootable USB? I read that only the Pro-Version gives exact test results... 
Today i retry to reproduce the mentioned bug for the umpteenth time and approximately one out of 5 gnome screenshot takes a screenshot of the chrome browser (actual active window) but with other tabs (closed some time ago) and a wrong time in the task-bar.
when I am taking a "select area to grap" shot of my clock in the task-bar at 10:31 i get a pic with my clock showing me 10:14!!!!

Comment: @ElderGeek i did the ram test with memtest86 with help of a USB stick. Everything looked fine, no error occur!

Comment: Interesting.  What are your Time and Date settings? What version of the kernel are you running? are you using the `-d --delay` parameter? What video card are you using? My apologies for the scatter -gun questions but I am completely unable to duplicate your results running 16.04 kernel 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP nor can I seem to find mention of anyone else experiencing your results. Is this related? http://askubuntu.com/questions/133532/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-chromiums-search-suggestions-and-instant-search-res

Comment: Time&Date ist set to automatically and showed in the menu bar.
'Linux precision 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP'. I am not using delay parameters. I have a  video card (nvidia GM107GLM) and a on board video card (intel). Im using nvida drivers 367.35 from nvidia-367. The post in the link is not relevant. I am taking a lot of screenshots of my menu bar now and did not find a correlation! Sometimes the photographed time is 12 minutes bevor the time I took the photo, sometimes 15, 8 or 11 minutes... and maybe 1 out of 5 is the right time!

Comment: Today i want to take a screen-cast to document the strange behaviors. While i was taking the video everything looked fine (achieve to reproduce the screenshot errors mentioned) and then when i was looking at the video i saw everything different! The image of the video is constantly flickering between to different desktops, one on i was actually working in the present and the other a image of the past.  So now i can understand why there is always a different behavior in taking a screenshot (due to the random flickering). What can be the problem??  https://youtu.be/EV2oorPKyN0

Comment: FYI, there are better tools to take snapshots of web sites and PDFs that don't suffer from the size restrictions of your computer screen.

Comment: Are you sure you open the new screenshot image file? may be you opened an older screenshot file?

Comment: @AnwarShah yes i am sure. Did you see the video?

Comment: any idea what it could be?

Comment: "dkms status" give me that:

bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
i915-4.6.3-4.4.0, 1, 4.4.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
i915-4.6.3-4.4.0, 1, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.24, 4.4.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.0.24, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed

is that normal?

Comment: I have a dell xps 15 9550 and the same problem! But I didn't have it when I first installed ubuntu... so I think it's something driver related, but I had no luck in fixing this... I also tried updating the intel drivers

Comment: @justmyfault At fresh install where no problems. i updated also intel drivers a couple of days ago. But had this problems before intel updates. Now i have a problem in (re)installing nvidia drivers even if in the past i was able to install them. look here http://askubuntu.com/q/833328/543758

Comment: @ManuelBellini I have the same exact problem with the nvidia driverse! (albeit with a slightly different laptop, in particular I have an Nvidia GTX 960M card)... I guess the screenshot problem and the driver problem are related then...

Comment: @justmyfault now i am thinking also that the nvidia driver installation problems correlate with the screenshot problems described by me here.  Did you record also your screen and observe similar flickering (my video youtu.be/EV2oorPKyN0 ) (but only watching the video, no flickering during recording)?

Comment: @marsUbuntux I have the exact same problem, the video capture shows a flickering and screenshot can show an old screen of more than 2 hours (I can clearly see it with the clock and the window I had opened at that time). I did not find a pattern or a solution yet, it's a precision 5510 (similar hardware that xps 9550), ubuntu 16.04, Quadro M1000M, drivers 367.57 installed but using the intel card, kernel 4.7.10. I had the issue with the nouveau driver as well. Any progress on your side?

Comment: @jebeaudet i have also a precision 5510. I have  no solution. I am working on my thesis and i am afraid to try new things out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to have this problem on an XPS 15 9550 with ubuntu 16.04. 
I tried to update to 16.10 to see if the problem was solved, but the upgrade did not go well so I reverted to 16.04 (thanks to [Timeshift](https://launchpad.net/timeshift)).

However I solved it by following ComBin's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome)

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

(actually I also removed the file 
"/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf", which I had previously tweaked)

The solution is basically to remove the intel driver and resort to modesetting, it should be the default behavior in new ubuntu versions (maybe it already is in 16.10, I didn't check):
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-Debian-Abandon-Intel-DDX

Note that this also solves problems with the switching of gpu via nvidia-prime (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833328/problems-with-running-nvidia-370-driver-with-nvidia-quadro-m1000m-ubuntu-16-04#comment1285236_833328))

Comment: thank you a lot! it resolved my problem. Did you now install nvidia 370 drivers with prime and are able to switch between nvidia and intel graphic card?

Comment: yes I have nvidia-370 and nvidia-prime installed and the gpu switching works as intended

Comment: I have the Dell XPS 13 without the NVIDIA card -- have the exact same issue. Removing the Intel driver is not an option :)

Comment: Please note the solution is removing the X.org intel driver not the whole intel driver, there is no harm in doing so since the modesetting xorg driver accelerates 2D via opengl!

Comment: Ah thanks -- just removed it an the problem is gone. But now some of the graphical UI transitions seem to be gone.

Comment: graphics performance is unbearably slow now with the removal of the intel graphics driver!

Answer (score 1):

Getting a screenshot of the actual active window (your desired event) with Ubuntu 16.04 and gnome-screenshot is as simple as holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and Tapping <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> You will be prompted where to save the screenshot. Try it, it works.

Edit:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will result in the entire visible desktop being copied to the clipboard and you can paste the image into whatever document you desire.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will provide a crosshair that you can use to select a portion of the screen to capture to the clipboard which again you can paste into whatever document you desire.

Tested on fresh install of 16.04.1

Alternatives to gnome-screenshot can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)