# Problems with running Nvidia-370 driver with Nvidia Quadro M1000M Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

Pc: Dell Precison 5510

Ubuntu version: 16.04

Graphic cards:

- Intel Corporation HD Graphics P530
- NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM Quadro M1000M

I updated the microcode firmware for Intels graphic card with their tool.
Then I installed the nvidia-370 driver with nvidia-prime like so:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 nvidia-prime
```

At reboot I had a login loop. Then i switch in TTY the GPU to use like suggested in the comments:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

I can login again. If I look at `/etc/modules` I see this:

```
 i915 
 bbswitch 
 nouveau 
 nouveau
```

When i am opening NVIDIA X server Settings, i don`t see any GPU to select.

I posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/801378/543758) about another problem that affects me. Maybe they correlate with each other?

what can I try?

How should i set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`?

---

if I `sudo apt-get update` I receive this massage at the end:
`W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)`

Comment: When `Nvidia` drivers were installed `Nouveau` drivers should have been `blacklisted` this might have caused a conflict but probably something else is going on. You didn't need to purge `nvidia*` in TTY, you could have used `sudo prime-select intel` in TTY and kept your drivers around for later.

Comment: should i blacklist `Nouveau` before i install the nvidia driver?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Now i did it like you said. Intalled nvidia-370, reboot and there again the login loop. Then TTY and `sudo prime-select intel`, reboot and i can login again... 
If i open etc/modules i see `i915; bbswitch; nouveau; nouveau`. So why two times nouveau? And should there a 'nvidia' also?

Comment: You should purge and `blacklist` nouveau to remove it from the equation forever.  Eliminate the clutter... Don't have time to fully answer your question now, will look later.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Can you provide me please a full description how to proceed to get everything clean?

Comment: I wish I knew how. I haven't setup Nvidia drivers successfully myself. Try this link: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau] Please pay attention to last answer!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix last answer says that there is no need to blacklist nouveau. Tried now nvidia-367, same login loop. Im using `ligthdm` as windows manager and grub setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth"`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'll be away from my computer all day and can't research anything. :(

Comment: It actually says you don't need to blacklist nouveau **IF** you install the drivers using 'System Settings', 'Software & Updates', **'Additional Drivers'** but you used 'sudo apt-get install'

Comment: I have the same issue!
Since I don't urgently the nvidia card under linux, I just purged the nvidia drivers for me the moment, but this is far from ideal. When I first installed ubuntu 16.04 (last april) I also installed the nvidia drivers with the systems settings GUI and everything was fine for a while... I can't exactly tell which update broke things

Comment: @justmyfault it would be interesting to install the old dated drivers, but i dont know how... simply taking drivers lower than nvidia-370 ? for examle nvidia-367?

Comment: @marsUbuntux at the moment I have the problem WITHOUT any nvidia driver installed... But since ubuntu 16.10 came I think I'll try to update in a few days and see what happens

Comment: @justmyfault it would be nice if you can report here after update. thanks