# gnome-screenshot -- All I see is my wallpaper in the screenshot

Tags: 16.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I was just looking for a Ubuntu snipping tool and found gnome-screenshot. However, when I use Screenshot app in Ubuntu 16.04, it just takes a screenshot of my wallpaper, not of any windows -- doesn't matter if I "**Grab the whole screen**", "**Grab the current window**", or "**Select area to grab**" -- all I ever see is part of, or my entire, wallpaper.

Am I missing something?

This is a **VM in Virtualbox**, but I have 3D acceleration enabled.

Comment: Have you tried another screenshot tool such as shutter? Do you have the same result?

Comment: how if you press the key "**Print Screen**" on your keyboard?

Comment: So weird. With gnome-screenshot, the Print Screen button takes a screenshot of the entire.... wallpaper. And Shutter, upon opening and clicking "Selection", all my windows pretty much disappear and all I see is my wallpaper. Seems like both of these apps think I want to take a screenshot of (or selection of) my wallpaper, and wallpaper only. Hmmm.

Comment: how if you disable 3D acceleration ? same result ? maybe in [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/801378/screenshot-problem-ubuntu-16-04), you can get clue